# Would be good to include your freelancer account in your Resume / CV when applying for a job?

Tags: freelancing, interview, resume

I've been working as a **freelancer** for about two years in [vWorker](http://www.vworker.com/). Any person can visit a coder's profile, and see in how many projects the coder has worked on, (if the coders allows) see how much the coder obtained in each project, ratings, feedbacks, etc.

Would be good to include a freelancer account in your Resume / CV when applying for a job?
Is it something you would do if you have finished several projects there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your profile doesn't show lots of good feedback, a reasonable workload, and a pay that is in line with what you're going to ask for, leave it out.

Beyond that, just follow standard guidelines for writing a resume - make sure that you highlight the parts that are most relevant to the work you're applying to, and spent less space on the parts that are not relevant/likely to distract. Provide as much detail about the work that you've performed on vWorker as is relevant, don't just include just the reference to vWorker when describing the work you've done there. Use the reference as proof that the work was done, and was quality work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can. But you can only mention it in your extra curricular activities I guess.

Answer (score -3):

Rather dont bother including it into your resume and instead upload the apps/programs that you've created to a github or bitbucket account. That when whoever views your resume can instead view the code that you've written.

Also, you don't want whoever is viewing your resume to be able to see how much you where getting paid for those projects as it will most likely be much less than what you will be paid in the programming job that you are applying for.

Comment: The code is almost certainly the property of the hiring firm and cannot be uploaded to github and friends.

Comment: I dont think you understood me. I didnt mean that he should upload the EXACT projects he did for company's as of course that is the company's property! I meant that he could create projects that were similar to the ones he had already done and instead upload those.